# How to find and edit Vsync for games using Ubuntu

Tags: framerate

I’m using Ubuntu on an already slow device and in order to lower the graphics of a game (The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth) I need to access Vsync to turn it off to hopefully up the FPS.

(I’m on a chromebook if that makes any difference.)

Comment: There is no global settings for Vsync .This is application specific as far as I know. Which gpu is on your chromebook ? There might be a settings manager or so for your GPU which might disable the vsync entirely . I don't know. But you have to disable it manually in your game settings.